# Boto AWS S3- "NoSuchKey", when the Key does indeed exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a function to read the contents of an AWS S3 '`key`'. The key is a `JS file` called `colorInfo`. I can navigate to the file from the S3 interface and I can access it successfully from the python shell. 
Upon recreating the python shell steps within a function and inserting the function into the rest of the python file, it renders me an error from within the Django debug console when called--

```
'S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found' and: '<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist</Message<Key>http:/s3.amazonaws.com/org.gomoto.izmo/Colors/2014/
14ram/14ram1500tradesmanreg4a/colorInfo.js</Key>'
```

the '`colorInfo.js`' lives within the '`14ram1500tradesmanreg4a' key`. Does anyone have any insight? I can provide more details if it may help anyone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is correct. The object you requested does not exist, because you are requesting the wrong object. Read it carefully:

```
<Key>http:/s3.amazonaws.com/org.gomoto.izmo/Colors/2014/ 14ram/14ram1500tradesmanreg4a/colorInfo.js</Key>
```

That's the key, which *only* contains the path and filename. It does not contain the bucket, or "http" or the hostname.

This means that instead of trying to download `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object` you appear to be linking to `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/http:/s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object`.  It looks as if, at some point, you are providing a full URL, where you should be providing only the key.

Comment: So the fact that I can navigate to [ http:/s3.amazonaws.com/org.gomoto.izmo/Colors/2014/
14ram/14ram1500tradesmanreg4a/colorInfo.js ] from my web browser does not mean that the Key is available?

How should I be accessing that python file from within my python code then?

Comment: @Richael the **key** for that object is `Colors/2014/...`.  It is not `http://...`.  You are getting the error because you are trying to request a malformed url. The key is *only* the path and filename. The fact that the key shown in the error contains extraneous information tells you that you are not requesting what you intend to request from S3.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael. We fixed our bug

Comment: @Richael Hi! How did you solve this problem? I am too facing the same problem. Could you suggest me please.

Comment: @Kakar are you sure it's the **same** problem?  The problem here was requesting the wrong key, apparently because of a bug that was doubling-up some combination of `http://...http://...` when building URLs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, I thought `Instance.image.url` was the key of that object. But I was wrong. If possible could you please have a look at my [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600110/how-to-get-the-aws-s3-object-key-using-django-storages-and-boto3) please.