# How to get the aws s3 object key using django-storages and boto3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, django-storage

I am using django-storage and boto3 for media and static files using aws s3. I need to get the object key of aws s3 bucket, so that I can generate a url for that object.

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'django-bucket'

key = ???

u = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key,'ResponseContentType':'image/jpeg', 'ResponseContentDisposition': 'attachment; filename="your-filename.jpeg"'}, ExpiresIn = 1000)
```

These are in my settings:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "my_access_key_id"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "my_secret_access_key"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "django-bucket"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com"
# static media settings
STATIC_URL = "https://" + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "admin/"
```

I can get the file path of the image file

```
ui = UserImage.objects.get(user=user_id, image=image_id)
url = ui.image.url

'https://django-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_image/1497598249_49.jpeg'
```

But I don't know how to get the s3 object key so that I can generate a url for that object.

Comment: That *is* a URL for the object. The S3 bucket is django-bucket and the S3 key is media/user_image/1497598249_49.jpeg.

Comment: @jarmod Yes. But is there any way to get this programatically using boto3 or django storage packages? Or should I use split/replace or some regex to get it from the image's url?

Comment: Why have you set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`? A quick check of the docs suggests that with that set to the default of `True`, `ui.image.url` would *automatically* return a pre-signed URL -- you wouldn't have to generate one.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot oh! I didn't know. I thought `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` would be the goto to make the static files public. Is there any way to response back with that pre-signed url and change its headers, basically  `ContentDisposition` and ContentType, so that it will be downloadable? Or should I change the `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True` to make it work?

Comment: I find myself desiring to get the key of a file because that seems to be the only to query if a file actually exists. Situation arose where objects were created but not actually saved in aws s3.

Comment: I wondered about this as well and didn't find a way. Essentially, the .name is the key but it has to be prefixed with the 'location' setup for the storage type the object uses. So if location is 'images', .name will be 'blabla.jpg' and you need to manually prefix. The .url does this automatically, but there are many reasons you don't want to access S3 by https.

Answer (score 5):

It would seem the prefix can be constructed from the file field 'storage' location value and the file 'name' (which is a path from the 'location' to the file - it includes what most of us think of as the file 'name').

Here's a quick demo of a function that should get the job done:

```
import os

def get_file_key(file_field):
    return os.path.join(file_field.storage.location, file_field.name)
```

Use as follows:

```
prefix = get_file_key(my_model_instance.relevant_file_field)
```

Notes:

You'll probably want to implement error catching sanity checking in/around the function as appropriate for your needs - for example the function will raise an AttributeError if the file_field is None - and in most scenarios you almost certainly wouldn't want to end up with just the location if for some reason the field.name returned an empty string as a result of a bug or just because that was saved somehow (or '/' if the location wasn't set)

Answer (score 3):

You can get s3 Object key by:

```
ui = UserImage.objects.get(user=user_id, image=image_id)
bucket_key = ui.image.file.obj.key

'media/user_image/1497598249_49.jpeg'
```